# Clickonce auto start on login

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple dock in VB.NET. Now I want to make it so when the user installs it, the application automatically adds itself to the startup items so that it will start after every system login or restart.

I want the solution to applicable for all OS'es (Windows 7 to Windows 10).

Thanks

Comment: why do you want it to start automatically on startup? Rather give an option whether the user wants it to run at startup.

Comment: @Rakitić its a dock application which contains shortcuts for several other apps and websites. For ease of use i created that app. i do not think there is need of downvoting for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this by using the registry:**

This code below adds the application to the startup, in the registry:

```
'variables
Dim name As String = Application.ProductName
Dim location As String = Application.ExecutablePath
'registry key
Dim regestry As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
'adds key to registry
regestry = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
regestry.SetValue(name, """" & location & """")
regestry.Close()
```

This requires admin privileges, here is a good tutorial on that: http://www.downloadinformer.com/2014/01/how-to-make-vbnet-application-always.html

Comment: The link is broken