# How to launch Windows Form Application .exe on PC in specific time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

For now I have desktop application which I invoke by clicking twice on exe version. I want to launch that exe version automatically. Application is made in Visual Studio 2013 using visual basic. How to automatically launch exe version, for example in 4 pm every day?

Comment: what you means by predefined time?

Comment: Please be more specific, and show us what you've tried so far. I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and maybe take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). anyway -as a hint- you might consider using a `Timer`

Comment: I want that process start automatically in 4 pm.

Comment: If you want to just launch the executable you might create a task using Windows Task Scheduler. but since you have a login form, the application will just stop there. Do you want to bypass the login? that means the login window would be useless!

Comment: I want to launch the executable file, but I do not want to bypass login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Task Scheduler would be the easiest but only if you are OK with it running only when the user is logged on or you'll never see the interface. Even a console application won't show if you set it to run whether user is logged on or not. I assume this won't be an issue since you'd have to be logged on to enter login credentials so your program would continue.

Comment: I think this would be a best solution. Maybe is better to replace my code with a new web page (.aspx) and create .vbs script to call it through the Task Scheduler.

Comment: If it works out for you, then please come back and select my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate application in VB.NET, which you can set to start at start up ([Clickonce auto start on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037224/clickonce-auto-start-on-login/38037297#38037297)). Then, every minute, using a timer you can check if the time is 4pm and if it is, then launch the application.