# Revit Model Opening Automation

Tags: revit-api, bim

I work with large revit model and lot of time goes in model opening, unfortunately I have to open the model with all Worksets ON for my work. Looking for a way to schedule a task for Revit to start opening the model at a certain time.

I tried task scheduler in Windows to automate the model opening task in Revit but it did not work. Looking for an automated way to open the revit model at the desired time and I can start working on it instead of waiting for a longtime to open the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply launch Revit.exe at a specified time and provide the project document as an argument to open it. There are numerous ways to launch a Windows executable at a specified time, e.g.:

- [Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-an-application-exe-from-c)
- [How to launch Windows Form Application .exe on PC in specific time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048247/how-to-launch-windows-form-application-exe-on-pc-in-specific-time)